# How to fix NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

I am trying to update my menu items to add and edit menu items and I am having trouble moving to the next page. Although the menu Items updates or get added.

views.py

```
def addMenu(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = menuForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('menu')
    else:
        form = menuForm()
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'addMenu.html', context)


def editMenu(request, id):
    menu = get_object_or_404(Menu, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = menuForm(request.POST, instance=menu)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('menu')
    else:
        form = menuForm(instance=menu)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'editMenu.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Restaurants(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restaurant_name


class Menu(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.ForeignKey(Restaurants, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurants', null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

urls.py

```
lpatterns = [

     path('', views.showRestaurants, name='restaurants'),
     path('add/', views.addRestaurants, name='add'),
     path('edit/<id>', views.editRestaurants, name='edit'),
     path('<id>/delete/', views.deleteRestaurants, name='delete'),
     path('menu/<id>', views.showMenu, name='menu'),
     path('addmenu/<id>/', views.addMenu, name='addmenu'),
     path('menu/edit/<id>', views.editMenu, name='editmenu'),
     path('menu/<id>/delete', views.deleteMenu, name='deletemenu'),

 ]
```

edit.html

```
<form method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Update</button>

            </form>
```

Each time I click on update it takes me to this error page

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'menu' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['menu\\/(?P<id>[^/]+)$']
```

Although the menu item gets updated and added to my menu list

Comment: As an aside, you should consider changing your URLs and views to use `pk` instead of `id`, so that you are not clashing with Pythons built-in [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `menu` URL pattern takes an id,

```
 path('menu/<id>', views.showMenu, name='menu'),
```

but you are not providing an id when you try to redirect:

```
 return redirect('menu')
```

It looks like you should do:

```
 return redirect('menu', id=id)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I did not know I could do that.